# copy of a machine running WP still redirected to original

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect

I have a centos machine running WordPress. For security reasons, the traffic goes through a third-party company so it can filter possible malicious access to the site (it works like a firewall between this machine and all the traffic to it). I needed to run a copy of the machine to test some stuff. I copied it and run it on a different IP address, but the machine still redirected to the original one. I removed certs and created new ones and changed all DNS name to the new IP in httpd.conf. But that didnt solve the problem. Any ideas what configurations/changes I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you replaced your old site url to new ip address url in your database?

Comment: I replaced URL in httpd.conf and ssl.conf with new IP. If this should be done anywhere else, I don't know. Any ideas?

Comment: could you please share the both urls? and did you cloned the whole file and database in to your new machine right?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to share those info but yes. This is a dump of the original machine just removed certs and changed original domain name (www.example.com) to the new IP.

Comment: are you able to run www.newip.com/wp-admin url? if not, just rename the .htaccess file and check. and check on various browser too, and still are you seeing the same old url, test the site in https://www.hidemyass.com/proxy

Comment: I am but it gets redirected to the old URL. So 1.2.3.4/wp-admin gets redirected to www.original-url.com/wp-login. What should I change in .htaccess? There is no URL name there.

Comment: it may be network cache, test it on https://www.hidemyass.com/proxy
are you able to go phpmyadmin database access? if yes, find the old url in your database using **Search*** tab.

Comment: I can access phpmyadmin but wp-login gets redirected to WP dashboard on www.original-url.com. I will replace all occurences of old url with new IP in the DB. Hopefully it fixes the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Thats fine.

Comment: It was the DB. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you can start with:

1. Update the A record and CName record from your domain name provider.
2. Check if there is any other virtual host/server block config for your site. Update them accordingly and don't forget to restart your web server.
3. Check on the database if any old url exists, if yes, replace with new.

Hope that helps!